# php7.4 Xdebug xdebug.mode = debug is not working for me

Tags: php, xdebug-3

I have installed Xdebug on a Ubuntu 20.04 system.  I followed [this documentation](https://medium.com/@s73obrien/setting-up-vs-code-to-develop-through-ssh-remotely-can-be-a-bit-intimidating-but-you-can-do-it-c4e9b2b42190) , which I found to be quite well written, and got everything installed per the specs. (I used apt rather than yum, and placed the .so file into `/usr/lib/php/20190902` folder rather than the document's example.)

In that document, there is a reference to adding to the php.ini file (I added to `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` files).  Since the article doesn't specifically mention "sections" of the .ini file, I put them within the `[PHP]` section.  (This is consistent with the remark about putting right before the Quick Reference bit.)  I restarted Apache2 and the `phpinfo()` output now includes Xdebug, which it did not include before.  All well and good.

The trouble I'm having is that although I set `xdebug.mode = debug` in the php.ini files, the `phpinfo()` output tells me that `xdebug.mode` is set to `develop`.  Consequently, Step debugger shows as Disabled in my configuration.  I cannot see why.

These are the lines I've added to each of those php.ini files:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

#zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug,develop,trace

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9900
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.log_level = 7
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.mode=debug,develop,trace
```

And here are the key excerpts from the `phpinfo()` output:

[image]

On a whim, I tried placing all of those settings also within a new section of php.ini which I called `[xdebug]`.  When that didn't work, I tried `[Xdebug]`.  I restarted Apache2 after each attempt, but the symptom never changed.

What might I be missing?

Comment: Let me suggest you a video I made not so long ago about how to install xdebug with 0 extra config, it is en spanish but can be helpful! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPad8HFLnzo

Comment: no use,i have gone through video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, being on Ubuntu 22, PHP 8.1 and xdebug 3.1.2, the solution was to edit not the `php.ini` file but the `xdebug.ini`. For example :

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

After this a restart for apache

```
sudo service apach2 restart
```

Then I was able see the changes in phpinfo and finally connect to PHPStorm debugger.